# Is it possible to get notified when a new class is added to the runtime? (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

The Objective-C runtime allows one to dynamically create and register class pairs using `objc_allocateClassPair` and `objc_registerClassPair` respectively. Is it possible to get notified when a new class is added to the runtime? (I'm only concerned with registered Objective-C classes if that helps, unregistered classes would be a bonus.)

If it is not possible to be notified, what is the next most efficient thing? Most iOS devices have severe computational constraints, so my options are limited. I'm open to a bit of runtime hackery if that would make it possible. I realize that I could just hook `+load`, but that would only work with NSObject subclasses, and not pure Swift classes.

"*Pure* Swift classes? But pure Swift classes are not Objective C classes!" you say? Think again. Try introspecting a pure Swift class using the runtime, and you'll see that there is more to it than meets the eye! "How can one end up having a Swift class being added dynamically?" Well, I could just load a dynamic framework that uses Swift!

Since @SpaceDog asked, this is for a developer utility that I'm working on. For further clarification: I do not myself know when `objc_allocateClassPair` or `objc_registerClassPair` will be called, since my project is a library.

Comment: what do you mean by that? In which situation a class would be added to the runtime? Give an example.

Comment: @SpaceDog: Classes can be dynamically allocated using `objc_allocateClassPair`, and then be registered via `objc_registerClassPair`. The reason is quite simple: I'd like to monitor the list of registered classes for a developer utility that I'm working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer: No.

## Long answer: Sort of.

There are two methods you can go about this. Both of which require a watchdog thread and polling, sadly.

**There is no synchronous callback you can piggy-back onto without rewriting symbols.**
<sub>(of course, if that's an option, you have a whole host of other solutions)</sub>

1. First option, which only uses public APIs: you could watch for `objc_getClassList`'s count to change at any point.

   The issue with this solution is that it will force-load all classes that may be simply loaded into the shared DYLD cache into user space. This only happens once, but it is a sizable performance hit to do so. Certainly not good for cold start time.

   Note: The sort order for `objc_getClassList` is not well-defined (internally it relies upon an unstable hash-table), so there's not a good way (e.g. less than `O(N)` storage/time) to determine which class specifically was added.

---

2. The second option, and probably the more viable one, is to (ab)use the debugger specific API `gdb_objc_realized_classes`.

   This is a `NXMapTable` (super old hash table implementation used inside the objective-c runtime) of class names (`const char *`) to Class pointers (aka. `objc_class`).

   Note: `NXMapTable` is no longer in public headers since a really old version OSX (10.4?), so you'll want to take the latest version of `maptable.h` from [Apple Open Source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/).

   Example usage:

   ```
   #import "maptable.h"

   extern NXMapTable *gdb_objc_realized_classes;

   int main() {
       printf("Realized classes: %d\n", NXCountMapTable(gdb_objc_realized_classes));

       Class superClass = [NSObject class];
       Class myKls = objc_allocateClassPair(superClass, "TestClass", 0);
       objc_registerClassPair(myKls);

       printf("Realized classes: %d\n", NXCountMapTable(gdb_objc_realized_classes));
   }
   ```

   Also note: `gdb_objc_realized_classes` has **zero** thread-safety guarantees, so if you have multiple threads potentially registering classes, you may run into issues.

---

These solutions allow you to know *when* a class is added, but not necessarily the specific class that was added.

Finally, if you're worried about memory (as you probably should be considering the Foundation framework alone has 1500 classes in it), one option might be to keep a data structure similar to a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) of known registered classes, and then, when the result of `objc_getClassList` changes, figure out which class does not pass that bloom filter and you have the newest registered class.

However, as a probabilistic data structure, you will have false negatives - e.g. some classes may slip through the cracks if your pointer/name hashes aren't good enough.

Good luck.